# Como imprimir linha seguinte

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?
$result = $connection -> query("SELECT * FROM testemunhos") or die($connection -> error);
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
?>
<div class="item">
    <div class="quote-left">
        <img src="<?=$row['testemunho_icon']?>" alt=""/>
        <div class="ql-content">
            <p><?=$row['testemunho_texto']?></p>
            <cite>-- <?=$row['testemunho_cliente']?>, <span><?=$row['testemunho_empresa']?></span></cite>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-sep"></div>
    <div class="quote-right">
        <img src="<?=$row['testemunho_icon']?>" alt=""/>
        <div class="qr-content">
            <p><?=$row['testemunho_texto']?></p>
            <cite>-- <?=$row['testemunho_cliente']?>, <span><?=$row['testemunho_empresa']?></span></cite>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Eu quero que no `quote-right` apareça o registo seguinte da base de dados, desta maneira ele imprimir o mesmo registo em ambos os sepradores `quote-left` e `quote-right`

Alguma Sugestão?

Comment: Sempre vai ter um número par nessa consulta?

Comment: Pode ter ou não, depende dos testemunhos que vão entrar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma variavel contadora $i por exemplo se for par você muda a class para quote-right e se não coloca quote-left.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Adicionei exemplo genérico na resposta do Lucas.
Consegue fazer a implementação no seu código?

Answer (score 0):

A melhor solução para isso é usar a função mysql_data_seek ou similar de acordo com o sgdb.

Está função te permite controlar o ponteiro de leitura dos registros na tua consulta SQL.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Answer (score 0):

**Márcio**, é preciso passar o resultado pra uma `array` e aí, com as chaves numéricas, descobrir qual é o próximo `$row`:

```
<?
$result = $connection -> query("SELECT * FROM testemunhos") or die($connection -> error);
$rows = [];

// -- passa o resultado para $rows
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// -- agora sim, para cada linha, com a chave ($key) numérica e ordenada...
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) 
{
    //$row_atual = $row;
    //$row_anterior     = ($key == 0 ? $rows[count($rows) - 1] :  $rows[$key - 1]);
    $row_proxima    = ($key == count($rows) - 1 ? $rows[0] : $rows[$key + 1]);
?>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="quote-left">
        <img src="<?=$row['testemunho_icon']?>" alt=""/>
        <div class="ql-content">
            <p><?=$row['testemunho_texto']?></p>
            <cite>-- <?=$row['testemunho_cliente']?>, <span><?=$row['testemunho_empresa']?></span></cite>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-sep"></div>
    <div class="quote-right">
        <img src="<?=$row_proxima['testemunho_icon']?>" alt=""/>
        <div class="qr-content">
            <p><?=$row_proxima['testemunho_texto']?></p>
            <cite>-- <?=$row_proxima['testemunho_cliente']?>, <span><?=$row_proxima['testemunho_empresa']?></span></cite>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Se precisar descobrir qual o testemunho anterior, descomente `$row_anterior`!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer listar tudo colocando o primeiro registro num formato e o segundo em outro, para isso é muito simples, basta você verificar o resto da divisão:

```
<?php
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM testemunhos") or die($connection->error);
$collection = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$i = 0;
foreach ($collection as $key => $value):
?>
<div class="item">
 <?php
$class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? "quote-left" : "quote-right";
$close_div = ($i % 2 == 0) ? ' <div class="quote-sep"></div>' : '</div>'."\n";
?>
    <div class="<?=$class?>">
        <img src="<?=$value['testemunho_icon']?>" border="" alt=""/>
        <div class="ql-content">
            <p><?=$value['testemunho_texto']?></p>
            <cite>-- <?=$value['testemunho_cliente']?>, <span><?=$value['testemunho_empresa']?></span></cite>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
 echo $close_div;
 $i++;

endforeach;
?>
```